# How to mount on Linux a QNAP external drive with LUKS partition

Tags: linux, password, encryption, luks, qnap

I need help to mount an external drive used on my QNAP TS-230 (latest firmware) to backup data. I set encrypted partition (LUKS) on this drive with a passphrase. I tried to mount that partition on a Linux system but when I enter the passphrase it doesn't work. I read the passphrase is hashed with the QNAP command `storage_util --encrypt_pwd pwd=<pwd>` but I have the same problem with the string returned.

Anyone have a solution?

Thanks.

I used the QNAP web interface to init the disk (*single partition, no others*), adding the encryption option.

When I run `sudo cryptsetup luksOpen /dev/sdb1 crypt_disk`, it asks for the passphrase and the response is `No key available with this passphrase.`. I tried with both password: in clear, and wrapped with the command `storage_util`.

Comment: It would be good to know what error you saw when you tried. Please [edit] your question to include it. Also was the drive encrypted with your QNAP or another Linux device?

Comment: How many partitions the disk actually has? Even if the QNAP admin interface showed only one, there might be an additional partition for the QNAP system software or other system metadata.

Comment: There's a one liner here https://forum.qnap.com/viewtopic.php?t=17988#p532803 but that looks pretty close to what you claimed you tried. I would try it with that sed command and also watch out in case the commandline is globbing your password. If your password has special characters or spaces you will need to be careful.

Answer (score 2):

I found the solution: QNAP limits the passphrase from **8 to 16 characters**. If you enter one *longer than 16 you do not get any errors or warnings*; I don't understand how it cut out the exceeded characters. I have used other QNAP and changed the oldest passphrase with 20 characters to "foofoofoo" and solved all my problems with `cryptsetup`.

Probably a **bug** in the QNAP OS ... **Thanks everyone**!